# Implementing a chrome extension that filters HTTP methods

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement a Google Chrome extension that filters HTTP methods. My idea, for now, is just to display all kinds of HTTP requests that starts at the client side, one after the other. I found out the method `chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(interceptRequest, null, ['blocking']);` which basically calls the interceptRequest method.
The interceptRequest method does the following:

```
function interceptRequest(request) {
  console.log('onBeforeRequest ', request.url);
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode("" + request.url);
  p.appendChild(text);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  document.body.append(request.url);
}
```

Basically it still does nothing, but at least I would like to print me out the urls, to start doing something, but also this easy task seems not to work.

Does anybody have an idea on how to make that work? If that work, from the `request` variable I should be able to get out also the HTTP methods and conclude my work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confusing the various script contexts that exist within a chrome extension.

take a look at this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html#arch

Comment: Thanks, I think after so much APIs just got changed. In the end I managed to make it work back there, but for future reference I mark your answer as the correct one.